# flutter Video Player Issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

about a month ago I wrote a small class around Video Player Package that I used in an APP to display a video from vimeo. Today I added this class to a new project and when initializing the player I get this:
E/flutter (20716): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
E/flutter (20716): #0      VideoPlayerApi.initialize (package:video_player_platform_interface/messages.dart:177:7)
E/flutter (20716): 
E/flutter (20716): #1      MethodChannelVideoPlayer.init ...

The odd part is it still works flawlessly in my other project using the same identical code/scaffold so I am at a loss at this moment to understand what is going on...

Comment: Did you reload your project after adding video player plugin?

Comment: Eventually it fixed itself after running Flutter Clean and every other command I could think off, but there seems to be an open request for this on GitHub to be fixed... anyway thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in your MainActivity

[image: add this Line]

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.videoplayer.*





class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: 
 FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(SharedPreferencesPlugin())
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(VideoPlayerPlugin())

}
}
```

Comment: What a coincidence  I was looking for this man! You saved me I was hunting for this since hours!